# Selecting rows from a table that have the same value for one field

Tags: sql, mysql, self-join

I have a MySQL database with these two tables:

```
Tutor(tutorId, initials, lastName, email, phone, office)
Student(studentId, initials, lastName, email, tutorId)
```

What is the query to return the initials and last names of any student who share the same tutor?

I tried `SELECT intials, lastName FROM Student WHERE tutorId = tutorId`  but that just returns the names of all students.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Please explain the background.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to retrieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the names of any student who share the same tutor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to join students against itself:

```
SELECT s1.initials, s1.lastName
FROM Student s1, Student s2
WHERE s1.studentId <> s2.studentID /* Every student has the same tutor as himself */
AND s1.tutorId = s2.tutorid
```

If you want to output the pairs:

```
SELECT s1.initials, s1.lastName, s2.initials, s2.lastName
FROM Student s1, Student s2
WHERE s1.studentId <> s2.studentID /* Every student has the same tutor as himself */
AND s1.tutorId = s2.tutorid
```

To get a list of Tutor - Students:

```
SELECT tutorId, GROUP_CONCAT( initials, lastName SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM `Student` 
GROUP BY tutorId
/* to only show tutors that have more than 1 student: */
/* HAVING COUNT(studentid) > 1 */
```

Comment: Doesn't this return all students of tutors that have at least 2 students? I doubt that is what you want.

Comment: @bananamana: which one? It wasn't exactly clear what you wanted, so I just threw a bunch of solutions - but now I'm curious what you wanted :)

Comment: The first one.  Thanks for your help, Konerak!

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT Tutor.tutorId, Student.initials, Student.lastName FROM Student INNER JOIN Tutor ON Tutor.tutorId = Student.tutorId GROUP BY tutorId`

This will return (not tested, but it should) a list of student initials and last names grouped by tutorId. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I'm trying to retrieve the names of any students who share the same tutor.

Answer (score 1):

Join Student table to itself

```
SELECT S1.intials, S1.lastName
FROM Student S1, Student S2 
WHERE S1.tutorId = S2.tutorId 
AND S1.studentId <> S2.studentId
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the query in SQL Server, im sure the idea is very close to mySql:

```
 select s1.initials,s1.lastname,s2.initials,s2.lastname from students s1 inner join students s2 on s1.tutorid= s2.tutorid and s1.studentid <> s2.studentid
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to make a query for every single tutorId. Pseudo-Code:

```
for id in tutorIds
    query('SELECT intials, lastName FROM Student WHERE tutorId = '+id )
```

If you wanna have a list containing all Tutors who actually have students, do a

```
SELECT tutorId FROM Student GROUP BY tutorId
```